# Java can't find main class and compile/run in VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

As the title indicates, I get an error on VSCode when I try to run a program that it can't find the main class. And this error just started happening the other day too, it was fine before.

Here's the error message:

Error: Could not find or load main Student

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Student

Comment: What the code? We can't tell what you need unless you show us what you have.

Comment: check if you install Multiple versions Jdk,and try to clean your workspace

Comment: thx @music2myear , i reinstalled the jdk and it works most of the time :)